# UIView animation cancels previous animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I have an `NSTIMER` that counts the time, and on t = 10, it fires an animation but during that time it might happen that another animation is running. This causes the previously running animation to cut off.

Any idea? i thought UIVIEW animations were ran in diff threads. I cannot use a willstop selector here since t = 10 might happen while another animation is running and might not have ended yet.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to start your animations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];`